# mvc 5 and jquery post not working second time

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

the code on the belows add/remove/list  products to cart, it works first time correctly, when i add second product its not refresh cart, when i refresh cart, i see second product. Anyone help me what i forget?

Note: Controller method returns JsonResult

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#vmCartModule').hover(
           function () {
               jQuery('#cart_list').stop(true, true).slideDown(400)
           },
           function () {
               jQuery('#cart_list').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp(100)
           }
        )

        new Request.HTML({
            'url': 'Sepetim/Sepet',
            'method': 'get',
            'data': '',
            'onSuccess': function (tree, elms, html, js) {
                //jQuery(".vmCartModule").productUpdate();
                mod = jQuery(".vmCartModule");
                jQuery.getJSON(vmSiteurl + "Sepetim/Sepet",
                    function (datas) {
                        if (datas == null) {
                            mod.find(".text-cart").html("Sepetiniz Boş"); // Sepet boş
                            mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                            mod.find(".total").html("");
                            mod.find(".show_cart").html("");

                        }
                        else if (datas.ProductCount > 0) { // Ürün sayısı
                            //mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                            mod.find(".cart_list").html("");
                            mod.find(".crt-text").html(datas.ProductCount + " ürün mevcut");

                            datas.CartList.reverse();
                            jQuery.each(datas.CartList, function (key, val) {
                                if (key < 4) {
                                    jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container").clone().appendTo(".vmCartModule .vm_cart_products");

                                    jQuery.each(val, function (key, val) {
                                        if (jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container ." + key)) {
                                            mod.find(".vm_cart_products ." + key + ":last").html(mod.find(".vm_cart_products ." + key + ":last").html() + val);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            mod.find(".total").html("Toplam Tutar: " + datas.TotalAmount + "TL"); //Toplam Tutar
                            mod.find(".show_cart").html(datas.ShowCart);

                        } else {
                            mod.find(".text-cart").html("Sepetiniz Boş"); // Sepet boş
                            mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                            mod.find(".total").html("");
                            mod.find(".show_cart").html("");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }).send();
    });

    function add_product_cart(elm) {
        var cart_id = jQuery(elm).children("span.product_cart_id").text();
        new Request.HTML({
            'url': 'Sepetim/SepeteUrunEkle',
            'method': 'post',
            'data': 'productID=' + cart_id + '&count=' + 1,
            'onSuccess': function (tree, elms, html, js) {
                mod = jQuery(".vmCartModule");
                jQuery.getJSON(vmSiteurl + "Sepetim/Sepet?callback=",
                    function (datas) {
                        if (datas.ProductCount > 0) { // Ürün sayısı
                            mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                            mod.find(".cart_list").html("");
                            mod.find(".crt-text").html(datas.ProductCount + " ürün mevcut");

                            datas.CartList.reverse();
                            jQuery.each(datas.CartList, function (key, val) {
                                if (key < 4) {
                                    jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container").clone().appendTo(".vmCartModule .vm_cart_products");
                                    jQuery.each(val, function (key, val) {
                                        if (jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container ." + key)) mod.find(".vm_cart_products ." + key + ":last").html(val);
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            mod.find(".total").html("Toplam Tutar: " + datas.TotalAmount + "TL"); //Toplam Tutar
                            mod.find(".show_cart").html(datas.ShowCart);
                        } else {
                            mod.find(".text-cart").html("Sepetiniz Boş"); // Sepet boş
                            mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                            mod.find(".total").html("");
                            mod.find(".show_cart").html("");

                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }).send();
    }

    function remove_product_cart(elm) {
        var cart_id = jQuery(elm).children("span.ProductID").text();
        new Request.HTML({
            'url': 'Sepetim/SepettenUrunSil',
            'method': 'post',
            'cache': false,
            'datatype': JSON,
            'data': 'productID=' + cart_id,
            'onSuccess': function (tree, elms, html, js) {
                mod = jQuery(".vmCartModule");
                jQuery.getJSON(vmSiteurl + "Sepetim/Sepet?callback=",
                     function (datas) {
                         if (datas.ProductCount > 0) { // Ürün sayısı
                             mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                             mod.find(".cart_list").html("");
                             mod.find(".crt-text").html(datas.ProductCount + " ürün mevcut");

                             datas.CartList.reverse();
                             jQuery.each(datas.CartList, function (key, val) {
                                 if (key < 4) {
                                     jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container").clone().appendTo(".vmCartModule .vm_cart_products");
                                     jQuery.each(val, function (key, val) {
                                         if (jQuery("#hiddencontainer .container ." + key)) mod.find(".vm_cart_products ." + key + ":last").html(val);
                                     });
                                 }
                             });
                             mod.find(".total").html("Toplam Tutar: " + datas.TotalAmount + "TL"); //Toplam Tutar
                             mod.find(".show_cart").html(datas.ShowCart);
                         } else {
                             mod.find(".text-cart").html("Sepetiniz Boş"); // Sepet boş
                             mod.find(".vm_cart_products").html("");
                             mod.find(".total").html("");
                             mod.find(".show_cart").html("");

                         }
                     }
                );
            }
        }).send();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors occurring?

Comment: no, there isnt any error, i think its working async and not finshed the first add roduct request

Comment: oh i see that the code working true on chrome, it has got problem on ie 10

Comment: its resolved, when i set false ajax cashe, ie works correctly. $.ajaxSetup({
                                // Disable caching of AJAX responses
                                cache: false
                            });